# How do I add a loading spinner for every request on backend Salesforce Cloud

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning

I would like to have some kind of interceptor or something that shows a loading spinner for every request made to the server, what I am looking is the most general form of it. I currently have a spinner component that holds the view and controller in it, but I am just wondering how do I make this general for every http request show it into the view maybe in the header or somewhere else.

This is the view part:

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="visible" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<div class="{!if(v.visible, '', 'slds-hide')}">
    <div class="slds-spinner_container">
        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I should somehow add to the controller some logic for other controllers to call it, but I just dont know and not quite sure what is the best way to do it!

For ex I have some controllers that makes a call to the server and I would like to somehow automatically show the loading spinner when such actions happens:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper)
{
    var getTeamAction = component.get("c.getCurrentUserTeam");
    getTeamAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if(response)
        {
            var t= response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.millTeamMembers", t);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Unable to getteam");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(getTeamAction);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, Whenever you are calling to server call doShowModalProcessing(comp) method and after getting response call doHideModalProcessing(comp).

Markup:

```
<div aura:id="modalProcessing" class="busy-backdrop busy-backdrop--open hideDiv">
    <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--large" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Helper:

```
doShowModalProcessing : function(component) {        
    var modal = component.find("modalProcessing");
    $A.util.removeClass(modal, 'hideDiv');
},
doHideModalProcessing : function(component) {

    var modal = component.find("modalProcessing");
    $A.util.addClass(modal, 'hideDiv');
},
```

CSS:

```
   .THIS.hideDiv {
    display: none;
  }
```